# Spring Boot JPA - find by 2 columns

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I don't know how to create a JPA query to get all records from my table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    private Message;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="message")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Message{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_account_to_message"))
    private Account account; //and then search by Account.id
}
```

SO I have 2 types of objects in A table (sometimes object is created from email, sometimes from a file):

1. one type without `user_id` (null) -> then I have to find all `A` object by searchning by `Message -> Account -> Id`
2. second type with `user_id` -> we can directly get `A` objects by values in `user_id` column

I want to get all records for specific `user_id` -> how to do that in most efficient way? I don't want to invoke 2 methods in repository:

```
 User user = userService.getEmail();
        List<A> aObjects= Stream.concat(ARepository.findByMessage_Account_Id(user.getId()).orElse(new ArrayList<>()).stream(),
                aRepository.findByUser_Id(user.getId()).orElse(new ArrayList<>()).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is it possible to create ONE repository method that finds all records for 2 different objects (one with `user_id` and second without `user_id`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this query is to complex for using derived from the method name query. As it stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.sample-app.finders.strategies):

> Although getting a query derived from the method name is quite convenient, *one might face the situation in which either the method name parser does not support the keyword one wants to use or the method name would get unnecessarily ugly*. So you can either use JPA named queries through a naming convention or rather annotate your query method with `@Query`.

So, I would suggest just write the following query:

```java
@Query("select aa from A aa left join aa.user u left join aa.message msg left join msg.account acc where (u is null and acc is not null and acc.id = :userId) or (u is not null and u.id = :userId)")
List<A> findByUserOrAccountId(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get values that fulfill the first requirement:  where (aa.user is null and aa.message.account.id = :accountId). ANd userId is the same as accountId

Comment: Yeahhh now it works:) Thank you:) It wasn't so easy...